# How do remove a Instagram permission from my website?

Tags: permissions, instagram, instagram-api, user-permissions

Instagram reviewed my page and everything was fine. Now my page is live and a lot users told me that they don't like that when they connect with their Instagram that we want permission to follow/unfollow.

In easy words, I want that my Users don't have to give me permission for follow/unfollow. But I can't find a way to remove it on Instagrams Dev page.

Answer (score 1):

<s>From their page [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/):</s>

That page has been updated. [Here is archived version of original page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170906043903/https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/) where it says the following:

> - **relationships** - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf

There is dedicated permission to just that - following/unfollowing accounts. Just remove request for that permission from your app at the time of authorization.